# Bookdown and Rmarkdown producing table and figure legends in italics

Tags: r, fonts, r-markdown, bookdown

When I use Rmarkdown or bookdown to produce tables and figures, the legends (and the table/figure text) are in italics. How can I overcome this such that the table/figure text is in bold and the legend is in plain text?

Here's some simple code:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  
  word_document: default 
  bookdown::word_document2: default
---


A normal paragraph.


```{r fig, fig.cap="A scatterplot of the data cars using base R graphics", echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)  
`x3


```{r fig2, fig.cap="**A scatterplot** of the data cars using base R graphics", echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)  
`x3

\
MARKDOWN DOES NOT PRODUCE THE TABLE/FIGURE NUMBERING, SO USE BOOKDOWN  
\
BOTH RMARKDOWN AND BOOKDOWN PRODUCE TABLE AND FIGURE LEGENDS IN ITALICS, NO MATTER WHICH IS USED.
````

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: This seems to be a word related bug, Bookdown and rmarkdown give non italic figure captions when knitting to pdf/html. can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks user12256545. Yes, that's correct. I've had problems knitting to pdf with my more complex file (not so with the simple example I gave), so stuck to Word as most basic. However, when knitting to both html and pdf, the Figure and Table label is also in plain text mode.  Is it possible to change the font of the labels to bold? Thanks.